# ReplaceAll and Regular Expression

Tags: java, sql, database

I am trying to insert tuples into newly created tables of a database schema I am building for SQL.

The issue is, I am to expect the first line to be

```
ssn INTEGER(9), cname VARCHAR(25), gender VARCHAR(6), age VARCHAR(3), profession VARCHAR(25)
```

But I want it to just be this:

```
ssn, cname, gender, age, profession
```

The previous method I tried with two splits, one for the space and the other for the comma is not working, so I thought using replace all would be easier. However, I am not sure what to try for the regular expression. How should these be created?

```
private static String parseFile (String[] x, Connection conn, 
String  tableName) {
    // assume the first line is the relation name layout
    String query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName;
    String firstLine = x[0]; 

    //System.out.println(firstLine);
    String[] splits = firstLine.split(" ");
    String[] finalSplit = new String[50];
    String finalString = ""; 

    for (int i=0; i<splits.length; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        String[] split2 = splits[i].split(",");
        //System.out.println (splits[i]);

        for (int j=0; j<split2.length; j++) {
            finalSplit[j+counter] = split2[j]; 
            //System.out.println (split2[j]);
            if (j%2 == 0)
                finalString += split2[j];
            counter += 1;  
        }
    } // end outside for 

    System.out.println ("The attribute string is: " + finalString);
    for (int i=1 ; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        String line = x[i];
        String Final = query + " " + finalString + " " + line;
        System.out.println ("Final string: " + Final);
    }
    return finalString;
}
```

I would appreciate a bit of guidance here.

EDIT: 
Some of the output is:

```
The attribute string is: ssnINTEGER(9)cnameVARCHAR(25)genderVARCHAR(6)ageVARCHAR(3)professionVARCHAR(25)
Final string: INSERT INTO customer ssnINTEGER(9)cnameVARCHAR(25)genderVARCHAR(6)ageVARCHAR(3)professionVARCHAR(25) 3648993,Emily,male,63,Consulting
Final string: INSERT INTO customer ssnINTEGER(9)cnameVARCHAR(25)genderVARCHAR(6)ageVARCHAR(3)professionVARCHAR(25) 5022334,Barbara,male,26,Finance
Final string: INSERT INTO customer ssnINTEGER(9)cnameVARCHAR(25)genderVARCHAR(6)ageVARCHAR(3)professionVARCHAR(25) 1937686,Tao,female,5,IT
```

Some of the input of x is:

```
ssn INTEGER(9), cname VARCHAR(25), gender VARCHAR(6), age VARCHAR(3), profession VARCHAR(25)
3648993,Emily,male,63,Consulting
5022334,Barbara,male,26,Finance
1937686,Tao,female,5,IT
```

Comment: Post few lines of `String[] x` you pass to `parseFile` method.

Comment: Using concatenated strings to build the query is a bad habit. Use [`PreparedStatement`](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/) in order to safely insert recoreds into the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
firstLine.replaceAll(" [A-Z]+\\(\\d+\\)","");
```

Explanation: This regex finds words with 1 or more capital letters immediately followed by a left parenthesis, one or more digits, a right parenthesis and a comma.

`replaceAll` replaces all instances of this with an empty string.

Comment: This is something I was looking for. Thanks!